# problem when saving images in wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

how to save the image  with tooltip in wpf.

so that when i open the image again,
the tooltip where i added must be displayed

Comment: i load a image and add a tooltip when mousedouble clicks on it. when i save the image, the tooltip must also be saved but hidden, so tat when i load the image again, the tooltip where i created tooltip initially must be shown.

Answer (score 1):

To do this you must save location of the tooltip seperaterly. and load it back again when you load image. Essentialy you can save picture in your custom format where in first line you would put X and Y location of the tooltip and any other info you need, rest of the file is image. When you load file read firs line and parse it manually, then load the rest of the file as image.